# Facing the issue in css for row hover in angular material table

Tags: css, angular-material-table

On mouse hover, the row of Angular material mat-table should be elevated with increased width on left and right side of mat-row. And the text on each cell of hovered row with red color.

Condition: mat-table is dynamic in nature (i.e., it can adapter any number of columns with column width auto fit. And table should be horizontally and vertically scrollable)

How to achieve this using css?

/* Outer container for overflow handling */

.table-container {

overflow-x: auto;

max-width: 100%;

}

/* Inner container for padding */

.inner-container {

padding: 0px 4px;

}

.mat-row:hover {

margin: 0px -4px;

z-index: 5;

box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

}

[Expected table image but with increased width on left and right side of hovered row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edh4y.png)

But due horizontal scrollbar and table-container it is the elevated row hides inside the div.